# Android ListView OverScrolling issue

Tags: android, listview

I have a small problem. I have a listView. After scrolling to the last item, if we try to scroll, we can drag all items to top. When we lift the finger from screen it comes back. I heard that this us a functionality of android. But can we disable it?

Comment: This is not Android's native behavior. Its most likely you have Samsung which adds this feature to its phones.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a device specific functionality. It's a overscroll animation for android < 2.3
It can be disabled. Look at

[setOverScrollMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29)

Comment: setOverScrollMode is availabe only from Api level 9. i am using Api level 8. Is there any other way in Api level 8 . anyway thanks for ur trouble.

Comment: Sorry. Can't really tell if there is another way for older versions of api. You can always try and hack into ListView by creating your own implementations that overrides a couple of things, but I haven't done, so I can't really help you here.

Comment: @user782298  have u find any solution for api level < 9